# what is the server name of mySQL hosted on EC2?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have installed LAMP on my EC2, running mariaDB. 
So now I would like to connect to mySQL, but what should my $servername be in the .php file (where i store the db_connect details)?

I've tried the Public DNS (IPv4) address of the instance provided on the EC2 dashboard, however, I am getting connection fail error when I run the .php files.
Am i using the right server name here?

Or is it because I need to set some access rights regarding Security group? I've added port 3306,tcp,0.0.0.0/0 to the Security Group but still getting the "Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@....."

I've also checked the my.cnf, which i assume it should not have any bind address values in it?

Comment: It seems this is credentials issue, port listening seems working fine. Are php files running on same box? if so, did you try using "localhost"?

Comment: Agreed - if you get a 'connection refused' or an access denied message from a server in ec2, it means you were able to be told that by the server, and that means the security group is open.  Security groups silently drop traffic that isn't allowed, so if a security group needs to be opened the symptom will be connections hanging before any data is transferred.

Comment: By the way, opening mysql on a public IP to 0.0.0.0/0 is a terrible idea.  Use the aws console to select "My IP" for that rule instead, if you're hitting mysql from your local workstation, or add the IP or a Security group for the client.   This is actually really important, because even if mysql has authentication too, it's trivially easy to DOS a mysql server without even successfully logging in.

Comment: @INVOKECloud, oh your suggestion works! Just wondering, why doesn't inputting the whole DNS address work?

Comment: Mysql root user by default supports "localhost", not remote access. When you use IP, it will be considered as "remote" connection and mysql rejects it. Apart from this I suggest you to follow @DanFarrell suggestions regarding security groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is credentials issue, port listening seems working fine. Are php files running on same box? if so, use "localhost", that should work fine. Here is tutorial on how to enable [remote connections](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/).

Good luck!

Comment: I suppose it turns out the _real_ problem is not having an appropriate  SQL user

Comment: Correct. User with appropriate permissions.